# uncaught TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am using react to try to populate data on render during a fetch call but am running into a problem. When trying to run a regular fetch api call using placeholder information everything works just fine.
However, when trying to get the "weather" or main sections of data to populate I am having a problem. The specific error I am receiving is "uncaught TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function"

```
 import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {  
    posts: [],
   
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://mm214.com/demo.php")

      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {console.log(posts)
        this.setState({ posts });
      }
      )
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      
         <header> 
         <h1>Weather</h1>
        <li>
        {this.state.posts.map(post => (           
           <li key={post}>{post.main} {post.temp}</li>
          )
          )
          }
         </li>


      </header>
    
        
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API response is a single JSON, not an array. If it is supposed to respond in both ways (either a single object or an array of objects), you can do a type check and update the state accordingly.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://mm214.com/demo.php")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((posts) => {
        if (Array.isArray(posts)) {
          this.setState({ posts });
        } else if (typeof posts === "object") {
          this.setState({ posts: [posts] });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <h1>Weather</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
            <li key={post}>
              {post.name} {post.main.temp}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the api doesn't return an array i tried calling it and it returns this

```
{"coord":{"lon":-117.1573,"lat":32.7153},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":296.62,...`
```

Check how your data should be because map only works on arrays.
If you want main and temp try accessing them manually post.weather.main for example

Answer (score 0):

If you want the weather from the API then i think you should try to map this.posts.weather instead of this.posts, since this.posts is an object which contains the array "weather". Your code could for example look something like this

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {  
    posts: [],
   
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://mm214.com/demo.php")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {console.log(posts)
        this.setState({ posts });
      }
      )
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      
         <header> 
         <h1>Weather</h1>
        <li>
        {(this.state.posts.weather) ?
            this.state.posts.weather.map(post => (           
               <li key={post}>{post.main} {post.temp}</li>
            ) :
            "No weather data available"
         )}
         </li>
      </header>
```